# What causes a jQuery cookie function to work ok when tested 'locally' but then has an error when tested live at hosting site

Tags: jquery, local-storage, session-cookies, jquery-cookie

I have searched through several previous questions, and I have not seen a similar bug & resolution. So here goes.

I am using several jQuery plugins, two of which are a jQuery Cookie plugin and a localStorage plugin for chrome browsers.

Building everything and testing locally, everything appears fine, cookie and storage wise.

Then my .js library crashes when a few errors are detected by the browser when loaded on a live server.

code:

```
$(function (){
    if( $.cookie('Cookie_1') == 'Visit_1' ){
        $('#ID1').doSomething();
        $('#ID2').doSomething();        
    }
    else if( $.sessionStorage('chromeCookie_1') == 'chromeVisit_1' ){
        $('#ID1').doSomething();
        $('#ID2').doSomething();
    }
    else{return false;}
});
```

I have several of these dual cookie type functions for navigation etc. But in the inspectors in FF and Chrome, it tells me that this is not a function.

I have no error message on the below function, which in my eyes is a carbon copy:

```
$(function (){
    if( $.cookie('Cookie_2') == 'checked_2' ){
        $('#ID3').doSomething();
    }
    else if( $.localStorage('chromeCookie_2') == 'checkedChrome_2' ){
        $('#ID3').doSomething();
    }
    else{return false;}
});
```

The only difference is that there are two jQuery actions/statements(*sorry don't have the vocabulary*) in the first `$.cookie` / `$.sessionStorage` function, and only one jQuery action/statement in the second example. And I know the first is a `sessionStorage` and the second is a `localStorage`, but again I have other more complicated `sessionStorage` functions with callback functions, that don't get an error.

Both(*indeed all*) of my `$.cookie` / `$.localStorage` functions are nested in the `$(document).ready(function(){`, if that matters.

Comment: What exact error message is displayed and what exact line of code causes it? If you aren't looking in the debug console, that's the first place to look for errors.

Comment: FF: $.cookie is not a function  -  and names the line which is: if( $.cookie('Cookie_1') == 'Visit_1' ){

Comment: If `$.cookie` is not defined, then you are not successfully loading the cookie plugin or you are trying to use it before it is loaded.

Comment: ok, so my chonology is logically wrong, I need to define all the cookies first?

Comment: That's not what I said at all.  You need to load the jQuery cookie plugin before you can use `$.cookie()` in your code.  `$.cookie()` is not built-in to jQuery.  It's a plugin that must be loaded separately.  My guess is you have the wrong path for the plugin script so it isn't loading properly when you run from the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 That was the key.  Not in that the plugin wasn't loading correctly, but I had another, old and scrap .js that was being loaded which there by caused a conflict. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.